# Camel Kafka Integration Issues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix

I am trying to integrate Camel with Kafka. I have implemented following route.

> ```
> <bean id="publisherPoint" class="org.vaida.esb.camel.orderdispatcher.OrderDispatcher.PublisherPoint">
> <property name="topicId" value="feedAlpha"/>
>   <property name="props">
>   <props>
>     <prop key="serializer.class">kafka.serializer.StringEncoder</prop>
>     <prop key="partitioner.class">org.vaida.esb.camel.orderdispatcher.OrderDispatcher.SimplePartitioner</prop>
>
>     <prop key="metadata.broker.list">localhost:9093,localhost:9094</prop>
>
>   </props>
> </property>
> <property name="reqMessage" value="RAONE"/>  
> </bean>
> ```
>
> RAJA

When I tested this with camel:run, I am able publish the message to kafka cluster. But When I have bundled and deployed to ServiceMix OSGi container I am getting following issue.

> 2014-02-26 17:00:17,190 | ERROR | #0 - timer://foo |
>   DefaultErrorHandler              | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core -
>   2.10.7 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-VVVVV-d-40084-1393430384926-0-11 on ExchangeId:
>   ID-VVVVV-d-40084-1393430384926-0-12). Exhausted after delivery
>   attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception
>   occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: RAJA]
>   org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
>   execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: RAJA]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1344)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:282)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:224)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:135)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:63)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/StringLike
>       at org.vaida.esb.camel.orderdispatcher.OrderDispatcher.PublisherPoint.publishAction(PublisherPoint.java:56)[238:OrderDispatcher:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:362)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:249)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:222)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       ... 43 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.StringLike not found by org.apache.kafka
>   [216]
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_51]
>       ... 51 more 2014-02-26 17:00:17,204 | WARN  | #0 - timer://foo | TimerConsumer                    | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core -
>   2.10.7 | Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: RAJA]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException - Exception occurred
>   during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: RAJA]]
>   org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
>   execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: RAJA]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1344)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:282)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:224)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:135)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:63)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/StringLike
>       at org.vaida.esb.camel.orderdispatcher.OrderDispatcher.PublisherPoint.publishAction(PublisherPoint.java:56)[238:OrderDispatcher:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_51]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:362)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:249)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:222)
>       ... 43 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.StringLike not found by org.apache.kafka
>   [216]
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_51]
>       ... 51 more

I suspected that this could be a scala version mismatch issue But using the same version of scala didn't fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure if the karaf jar that you used was an OSGi bundle. Can you double check that?   BTW Camel 2.13 has the new added camel-kafka component, I'm not sure if you were using it ?

Comment: @WillemJiang Thank you for your reply. My bundle is working fine if I comment kafka part so I do believe this is a valid bundle. Could you give me a pointer on kafka in camel 2.13. Where could you see that information.

Comment: My question is not about your application bundle, it is about the Karaf bundle which you installed into ServiceMix.